# Requests with dots at the end gives bad request 400

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, nginx-location

This is my configuration if I visit

`https://www.example.com.`

the dot at the end does not work

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/example.sock; # for a file socket
}

# Redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}


# SSL Request
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example;
    charset utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1;

    # Django media
    location /uploads  {
        alias /var/www/example/uploads;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/example/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /var/www/example/static/img/favicon.ico; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/example/robots.txt; # robots.txt
    }

    location /ntat {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*) http//www.example.com$1;
    }
}

# Normal Request
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name www.example.com
    charset utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /ntat {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1;
   }

   # Django media
    location /uploads  {
        alias /var/www/example/uploads;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }
    location /ntat {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1;
   }

   # Django media
    location /uploads  {
        alias /var/www/exam/uploads;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/example/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /var/www/example/static/img/favicon.ico; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/example/robots.txt; # robots.txt
    }

    location /timepass  {
        alias /var/www/timepass;  # Snake Game
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
       rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1;
       uwsgi_pass  django;
       include     uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_read_timeout 180;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure `default_server` as needed
- Don't use `rewrite` where you can simply `return`.
- Always specify `server_name` to ensure there is no different priority between `server`s
- Note `http//www.example.com$1;` (missing `:`)

The `www.example.com.` is [different server name for NGINX](https://serverfault.com/questions/843138/why-does-nginx-ignore-trailing-dots-in-the-host-header) than `www.example.com`, but you don't have a `server` that listens specifically for the dotted domain, thus it's best to use default server to mark the `server` block which will ensure matching properly.

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/example.sock; # for a file socket
}

# Redirect for example.com -> www.example.com (both ports)
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
}


# SSL Request
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example;
    charset utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1;

    # Django media
    location /uploads  {
        alias /var/www/example/uploads;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/example/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /var/www/example/static/img/favicon.ico; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/example/robots.txt; # robots.txt
    }

    location /ntat {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     uwsgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*) http//www.example.com$1;
    }
}

# Normal Request
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 80 default_server;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name www.example.com
    charset utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /ntat {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1;
   }

   # Django media
    location /uploads  {
        alias /var/www/example/uploads;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }
    location /ntat {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1;
   }

   # Django media
    location /uploads  {
        alias /var/www/exam/uploads;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/example/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /var/www/example/static/img/favicon.ico; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/example/robots.txt; # robots.txt
    }

    location /timepass  {
        alias /var/www/timepass;  # Snake Game
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
       rewrite ^(.*) https://www.example.com$1;
       uwsgi_pass  django;
       include     uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_read_timeout 180;
    }
}
```